# STDIN.getpass does not always show the key icon in the terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, io, passwords, credentials

How can I make sure that the key icon (see img for sample) always appears every time I call `STDIN.getpass`? The issue is intermittent, sometimes I get the icon and sometimes I don't. I could not find a reliable repro step.

[image]

How my code currently looks like:

```
  $stdout.flush
  # to hide the password while being typed in the terminal
  STDIN.getpass
```

- I thought `$stdout.flush` would resolve my problem but it did not.
- `STDIN.getpass` is being returned so its not assigned to any variables.

Comment: I only see the key icon when I pass a prompt: `STDIN.getpass "Enter password:"`

Answer (score 1):

They key icon itself isn't so much related to the `STDIN.getpass` function which is very simple and you can see it here:

https://github.com/ruby/io-console/blob/master/lib/io/console/ffi/common.rb#L9-L21

the `noecho` block is just setting the `tty_mode` to `noecho` (see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d92f09a5eea009fa28cd046e9d0eb698e3d94c5c/ext/io/console/console.c#L602)

So, I think this question is actually better as: "How come my `Terminal program` on `my operating system` doesn't always show a key icon, when the tty_mode is set to `noecho`.